# Lex regex gets some extra characters

Tags: c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I have the following definition in my lex file:

```
L   [a-zA-Z_]                                           
A   [a-zA-Z_0-9] 
%%
{L}{A}*                 { yylval.id = yytext; return IDENTIFIER; }
```

And I do the following in my YACC file:

```
primary_expression
    : IDENTIFIER            { puts("IDENTIFIER: "); printf("%s", $1); }
```

My source code (the one I'm analyzing) has the following assignment:

```
ab= 10;
```

For some reason, that `printf("%s", $1);` part is printing `ab=` and not only `ab`.

I'm pretty sure that's the section that is printing `ab=` because when I delete the `printf("%s", $1);` the identifier is not printed at all.

I really ran out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Let me know if I can be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're assuming that the string pointed to by `yytext` is constant. It is not.

The lifetime of the string pointed to by `yytext` is the lexical action of the associated rule. If that rule ends up returning, `yytext` will survive until the next time `yylex` is called. And that's it.

`bison`-generated parsers have a one-symbol lookahead. So by the time the parser executes a semantic action, `yylex` has been called again (for the lookahead); consequently, you can't use the saved value of `yytext` even for the last (or only) token in a rule.

Solution: copy the string. (I use `strdup`, but for whatever reason some people like to malloc and strcpy. If you do, don't forget about the NUL terminator.) And remember to `free()` the copy when you're done with it.

For reference: [what the flex manual says.](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/A-Note-About-yytext-And-Memory.html)