# On printing $1, it prints the value of $1,$2,$3, etc in bison

Tags: bison

I have written a program using flex and bison to parse a file. The yylval is returned properly by flex and when  I try to print the $1 value in my bison code, it also prints $2, $3..
How can I get rid of this. My flex and bison code is attached.

setuplog.l

```
%{  
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "setuplog.tab.h"
    #include <string.h>
    int yyline=1;

%}

time            ([0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
date            ([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)
identifier      [_A-Za-z0-9=\.:\\()&#'-]+    
%%


"(["{identifier}"])"    {
                            return(DATA);
                        }

{identifier}"!"         {

                            yylval=yytext;
                            printf("FRM LEXER ID = %s %s\n",yytext,yylval);
                            return(IDENTIFIER);
                        }

"["         {
                printf("OPEN\n");
                return(OPEN_TOK);
            }

"]"         {
                printf("CLOSE\n");
                return(CLOSE_TOK);
            }

">>>"       {
                return (START_TOK); 
            }

"<<<"       {
                printf("END TOKEN\n");
                return (END_TOK);
            }

"!!!"      {
                return(ERROR_TOK);
           }

"!"        {
                return(WARN_TOK);

            }

"Boot"      {
                return(BOOT_TOK);
            }

\n          {
                yyline++;
            }


{time}     {

                    yylval=yytext;
                    printf("FRM LEXER TIME= %s %s\n",yytext,yylval);
                    return(TIME);
            }

{date}      {

                    yylval=yytext;
                    printf("FRM LEXER DATE= %s %s\n",yytext,yylval);
                    return(DATE);
            }


{identifier}    {

                    yylval=yytext;
                    printf("FRM LEXER ID = %s %s\n",yytext,yylval);
                    return(IDENTIFIER);
                }


%%

int yywrap(void)
{
  return 1;
}
```

setuplog.y

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define YYSTYPE char*

extern int yyline;
int set_count=1;
FILE *fp;
extern char* yytext;
%}


%token  OPEN_TOK
%token  CLOSE_TOK 
%token  START_TOK   
%token  END_TOK   
%token  ERROR_TOK
%token  WARN_TOK  
%token  BOOT_TOK
%token  TIME
%token  DATE
%token DATA
%token  IDENTIFIER 

%start session
%%

session : boot_data section_start
        {
            printf("SESSION\n");
            fprintf(fp,"\n\nNO.OF LINES PARSED = %d\n",yyline);
        }
        ;

boot_data : head_desc statement head_desc head_desc
        {
            printf("BOOT_DATA\n");
        }
        ;

head_desc :OPEN_TOK statement CLOSE_TOK
        {
            printf("NON BOOT DATA--%s\n",$2);
            $$=$2;
        }
       |    OPEN_TOK BOOT_TOK statement CLOSE_TOK
        {
            printf("HEAD_DESCRIPTION\n$2=%s\nyytext=%s\n\n",$2,yytext);
            $$=$3;
            fprintf(fp,"\n[Boot %s\n",$3);

        }
        ;

statement : word
        {
            printf("WORD\n");
            $$=$1;
        } 
        |statement word 
        {
            printf("STATEMENTS\n");
            $$=$1;
            printf("STATEMENT VALUE== %s\n\n",$$);
        }
        ;

word :  TIME
        {
            printf("TIME\n");
            $$=$1;
        }
        |DATE
        {
            printf("DATE\n");
            $$=$1;
        }
        |DATA
        {
        }
        | IDENTIFIER
        {
            printf("IDENTIFIER\n");
            $$=$1;
        } 
        ;
 section_start : section_details 
        {
            printf("SINGLE SECTIONS\n");        
        } 
        |section_start section_details
        {
            printf("MULTIPLE SECTIONS\n");   
        } 
        |section_start head_desc section_details
        ; 

section_details :
            {
                fprintf(fp,"\n%d:\n",set_count); 
            }
            section_head section_body section_end
            {
                printf("SECTION DETAILS\n");
                set_count++;

            }
            ;

section_head : START_TOK head_desc START_TOK statement DATE TIME
             {
                printf("SECTION HEAD...\n\n%s===\n\n%s\n",$2,$4);
                fprintf(fp,"%s\n",$2);

             }
             ;

section_body :log_entry
            {

            }
            |section_body log_entry
            {

            }
            ;

log_entry : entry_prefix time_stamp body_statements
            {

            } 
            ;

time_stamp:DATE TIME
            {
                printf("DATE AND TIME\n");
            }
            |
            {

            }

            ;
body_statements : statement
            {

            }
            |head_desc
            {

            }
            ;

entry_prefix : ERROR_TOK
            {
                fprintf(fp,"%s","Error Message\n");
            }
            |WARN_TOK
            {
                fprintf(fp,"%s","Warning Message\n");
            } 
            |
            {
                printf("INFORMATION MESSAGE\n");
            }
            ;

section_end :END_TOK statement
            {

            }
            END_TOK head_desc
            {
                     printf("SECTION END...\n\n%s===\n\n%s\n",$2,$5);
                     fprintf(fp,"%s\n",$2);
            }
            ;


%%

yyerror(char *str)
{
    printf("Parse error: %s at line %d ,",str,yyline);
    yywhere(); 
}

yywhere()
{   
    int colon=0;
    int i;
    if(yytext) 
    { 
        for(i=0;i<50;i++) if(!yytext[i] || yytext[i] == '\n') break;
        if(i)
        {  
            if(!colon)  
            { 
                printf(" near: \"%s\"\n",  yytext);
                colon = 1; 
            }
        }  
        printf("\n");
    }  
}   

int main(void) 
{
    int i =remove("output.txt");
    fp=fopen("output.txt","a+");

    yyparse();
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lex regex gets some extra characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398448/lex-regex-gets-some-extra-characters)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the number one FAQ about bison/lex grammars.

Short answer: You need to copy `yytext` because it gets modified when lex reads the next token.

Longer answer in the [bison FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Strings-are-Destroyed.html).

Comment: I m copying it to yylval..when i use strdup i m getting only a single word instead of a sentence in bison

Comment: @ANU: If you mean the line yylval=yytext then no, you are _not_ copying yytext it to yylval. What you are copying to yylval is a pointer to the (first character in the) yytext character array, but the content of that character array is not copied, and will change when the Lex-generated lexer reads the next token. Try something like this: yylval=strdup(yytext)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy : if I do so how can I get a complete sentence in my .y file? If my text is: "hai how are you. (In next line) I'm fine", I need hai how are you and then i'm fine. Currently I'm getting both lines together.

Comment: @ANU: None of your rules match whitespace. You need to fix that. And you also need to read the flex manual, particularly the parts about copying `yytext`.

Comment: @rici: k..thank you. I'll go through the manual. Just for the time being can u tell me how to include thw rule to match the whitespace. What all changes should I make?

Comment: @ANU: I don't know. It depends how you want to handle whitespace. I can't tell if you want individual words, whole lines, or lines made up of the words but with whitespace normalized.

Comment: @rici: I require whole line. If my source code has lines,say,       1. !!! This is an error message                                       2. HAi                                                                3.! Warning for u                                                   In this case I want line no. 1 and 3 to be written to a file. Currently when I try to write line 1, all the three lines are written.

Comment: @ANU: That's because you're not copying `yytext`, which has somewhat unpredictable consequences (but it never does the right thing). Your bison grammar says: `statement: word | statement word`. Your flex scanner ignores newlines except to increment a line counter (Note: using `%option yylineno` is usually easier and less error-prone) so your grammar cannot limit a statement to a line. So you have still some work to do making a clear specification (not to me! In your scanner and your grammar.)